# Foreground color over components on Gallery

Tags: android, imageview, android-gallery

I'm implementing a application that allows user to drag pages though a Gallery to read a newspaper.

I wrote a Adapter that returns ImageViews with some Bitmaps loaded on application.

My problem is, the first image shows perfectly, the next ones has a gray foreground that make the image looks darker. After dragging somewhere the first one also get this foreground. How can I avoid my views getting this foreground?

Now I realized that the ImageViews are getting some value on alpha channel, this is why together with my black background the images look darker. How can I avoid it?

As solicited, here it's my code:

```
    Gallery view = new Gallery(context);
    view.setSpacing(10);
    view.setAdapter(new PageAdapter(context, pages));
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(600, 300);
    layout.addView(view, params);
```

And the Page Adapter

private class PageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        private List pages;

```
    public PageAdapter(Context c, List<Page> pages) {
        super(c, 0);
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Page page = getItem(position);

        ImageView image;

        if (convertView != null)
            image = (ImageView) convertView;
        else
            image = new ImageView(context);

        image.setImageBitmap(ImageUtils.rgb(page.loadNormal()));

        return image;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return pages.size();
    }

    public Page getItem(int position) {
        return pages.get(position);
    }
}
```

This ImageUtils.rgb was created to create a copy of any Bitmap into a Bitmap.RGB_586, but the same behaviour occurs.

Comment: Any chance the images has pixels with some opacity (alpha)?

Comment: @Marcos Post some relevant code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the unselectedAlpha property on the Gallery.

Either via your java (as per your example)

```
view.setUnselectedAlpha(1.0);
```

Of if you are using xml to declare the Gallery, add

```
android:unselectedAlpha="1.0"
```

Comment: Perfect, this is the right answer, I'll award the bounty as soon I'm enabled too (20 hours)